# i am uploading Image through AJAX in laravel, which is successfully uploaded but Successfull fucntion is not working

Tags: javascript, laravel

this is my ajax script which is uploading the image successfully in MySQL database but the success message is not showing alert or not working, and below is my store method:
I have seen other answers but is not working any other answer, like removing datatype: JSON, anyone reviews my code below and sorts out the mistake.

View file:

```
   $('#party_create_form').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '{{route('party.store')}}',
        method: 'POST',
        data:new FormData(this),
        dataType: "JSON",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
        success:function(data) 
        {
            alert('hi');

        }
    })
});
```

Controller File:

```
public function store(PartyRequest $request)
{
  $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'name' => 'required|unique:parties',
    'party_logo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
  ]);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
    
    $input['party_logo'] = time().'.'.$request->party_logo->extension();
    
    $request->party_logo->move(public_path('party_logo'), $input['party_logo']);
    
    $data = ['name' => $request->name,'party_logo'=>$input['party_logo']];
    
    Party::create($data);
    return response()->json();

  } else {

    return response()->json();
  }
}
```

Comment: What is inside the data? Would you please add a console log to the success function:
        success:function(data) 
        {
            console.log(data);
            alert('hi');

        }

Comment: i have used consol.log(datae); but honestly it is empty like not showing any response or msg on console

Comment: you don't send anything, to the client
try this `response()->json('data')`

Comment: i have used this now in controller return response()->json('data'); but saved image but still not doing anything like empty console and alert

Comment: why your content type is false?

Comment: because i am uploading image that y content type is false, if you have better solution, juts give me try, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
public function store(PartyRequest $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
      'name' => 'required|unique:parties',
      'party_logo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
    ]);

    if ($validator->passes()) {
    
      $input['party_logo'] = time().'.'.$request->party_logo->extension();
      
      $request->party_logo->move(public_path('party_logo'), $input['party_logo']);
      
      $data = ['name' => $request->name,'party_logo'=>$input['party_logo']];
      
      Party::create($data);
      $msg = "success";
      $array =  array("status" => 200, "msg" => $msg, "result" => array());

    } else {

      $msg = "Failed";
      $array =  array("status" => 400, "msg" => $msg, "result" => array());

    }
    return \Response::json($array);
}
```

Comment: i did try your code but happen nothing and image done, can u see my ajax code and tell if something needed, thanks

Comment: this some how solved problem, i tried your ocde and removed middleware from my sites, thanks

Comment: Please mark as verified if it is help for you thank you @MohsinKhan